# Printing backslash with letter a in python?

Tags: python

For the following code I want to print out the "tanim\anamul".
But when I execute this it show.
tanim\namul.
How can I solve this problem.

```
>>> print("tanim\anamul")
tanimnamul
```

Comment: instead do `print("tanim\\anamul")`. Note the double `\\` backslash

Answer (score 5):

Print in `raw` by adding an `r` before the quotations:

```
print(r"tanim\anamul")
```

or use '\\':

```
print("tanim\\anamul")
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
print("tanim\\anamul")
```

\ is used as an escape character to create a number of special codes:

`\t` = TAB
`\n` = LF
`\r` = CR
`\\` = \